# PHP incomplete code - scan dir, include only if name starts or end with x

Tags: php, dynamic, filenames

I posted a question before but I am yet limited to mix the code without getting errors.. I'm rather new to php :(

( the dirs are named in series like this "id_1_1" , "id_1_2", "id_1_3" and "id_2_1" , "id_2_2", "id_2_3" etc.)

I have this code, that will scan a directory for all the files and then include a same known named file for each of the existing folders.. the problem is I want to modify a bit the code to only include certain directories which their names:

1. ends with "_1"
2. starts with "id_1_"

I want to create a page that will load only the dirs that ends with "_1" and another file that will load only dirs that starts with "id_1_"..

```
<?php 

include_once "$root/content/common/header.php";
include_once "$root/content/common/header_bc.php";
include_once "$root/content/" . $page_file . "/content.php";

$page_path = ("$root/content/" . $page_file);

$includes = array();

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($page_path), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        $includes[] = strtoupper($file . '/template.php');
    }
}

$includes = array_reverse($includes);

foreach($includes as $file){
   include $file;
}

include_once "$root/content/common/footer.php";

?>
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at glob() , http://uk.php.net/glob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        // getFilename() actually gives the directory name, when it's um, a directory.
        $dirName = $file->->getFilename();
        if (substr($dirName, 0, 5) === 'id_1_') {
            $includes[] = strtoupper($file . '/template.php');
        }
    }
}
```

There's other ways to do this, but I tried to only add simple functions and logic, in hopes you will understand it.

*Ends with* would look like

```
if (substr($dirName, -2) === '_1')
```